# Java long regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to express a pattern like this
212425762_CHECK_08182014_1_USA

9 digits followed by an underscore, then 5 letters, another underscore, a 8-digit date, and"_1_USA".

This is what I got so far

```
String regex = "/^([0-9]{9})_([A-Z]{5})_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(20\\d\\d)(_1_USA)$/"
```

But it just doesn't work. I guess it's something wrong with the "_1_USA" part. Any ideas?

Comment: `it just doesn't work` ... could you also include the code where you are trying to use this regex?  Your regex pattern has a number of typos.  Also, why did you change your original question?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quantity `[1_USA]{1}` tells Java to match any *single* character of `1`, underscore, `U`, `S`, or `A`.  Instead, just use a literal string:

```
String input = "212425762_CHECK_08182014_1_USA";
String regex = "^([0-9]{9})_([A-Z]{5})_([0-9]{8})_(1_USA)$";
if (input.matches(regex)) {
    System.out.println("The input matches.");
}
```

In addition, your regex had some other typos, such as leading and trailing forward slashes, and incorrectly closed character classes.  Java, unlike some other languages, doesn't use forward slashes in its regex patterns (unless you mean them literally).

## Demo

Answer (score 1):

You've a couple of character classes where there shouldn't be.

This is probably what you mean.

Raw: `^([0-9]{9})_([A-Z]{5})_([0-9]{8})_(1_USA)$`

Stringed: `"^([0-9]{9})_([A-Z]{5})_([0-9]{8})_(1_USA)$"`

Expanded

```
 ^ 
 ( [0-9]{9} )                  # (1)
 _
 ( [A-Z]{5} )                  # (2)
 _
 ( [0-9]{8} )                  # (3)
 _
 ( 1_USA )                     # (4)
 $
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should replace a digit**

[image]

```
String regex = "^([0-9]{9})_([A-Z]{5})_(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])(20\\d\\d)(_1_USA)$";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has a typo, you have a `)` instead of a `]` after the `Z`. Try this:

```
String regex = "/^([0-9]{9})_([A-Z]{5})_([0-9]{8})_([1_USA]{1})$/"
```